# Date and Time Picker not getting updated from value selected

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

I am calling three methods from the onClick().

- The first one is for date picker
- second one for time picker
- third one for opening other fragment.

What I want is that when I click on the button in this fragment (i.e NeedBloodFragment), the date and time picker appears, and then the other fragment is opened.

As of now, I am getting the value of date and time as blank in this fragment as well as in the other fragment. The problem would most probably be that the three methods are being called in a weird way. I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

The essential parts of code are:

```
    public class NeedBloodFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_need_blood, container, false);

    Button button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();

             onCreateDialog(999).show(); 
             onCreateDialog(1999).show();
            openAppointments();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (id == 999) {

             DatePickerDialog d= new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), myDateListener, 2015, 6, 25);
             d.setTitle("Select Meeting Date");
             return d;
          }
          if(id == 1999) {
              TimePickerDialog t=new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        myTimeListener,
                        Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
                        Calendar.MINUTE,
                        true);
              t.setTitle("Select Meeting Time");
              return t;
          }
          return null;
       }


       private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
          @Override

          public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // arg1 = year
             // arg2 = month
             // arg3 = day


             StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

             sb.append(arg3).append("/")
                  .append(arg2+1).append("/").append(arg1);
             returnDate(sb.toString());

          }
       };

       private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myTimeListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                  int minute) {
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(hourOfDay).append(":").append(minute);
               returnTime(sb.toString());

            }
          };
       public void returnDate(String s)
       {

           MainActivity.selectedDate=s;
       }

       public void returnTime(String s)
       {

           MainActivity.selectedTime=s;
       }

    public void openAppointments()
    {
        fragment = new AppointmentsFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack( null ).commit();
    }
        else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }


        //dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

These are my questions to be precise:

1. Why is `selectedDate` and `selectedTime` not having any values and how do I rectify that?
2. Is there a problem in the way I'm calling the three methods?

Comment: at least comment your concerns before downvoting.

Comment: Doesn't look like a bad question to me. Just in case make sure you look over, how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask